# iOUSBFamily or USB Prober.app equivalent for macOS High Sierra?

Tags: usb, development

It seems [USB Prober.app is no longer a part of Xcode](https://superuser.com/a/814339/630402), and [iOUSBFamily hasn't been updated since 10.9.4](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=IOUSB)... is there anything equivalent available for High Sierra?

Comment: The debug/dev build of the kernel includes kexts and symbols with logging, if anyone is looking for this.

Answer (score 5):

It is directly integrated within `System Profiler`:

```
/System/Library/SystemProfiler/SPUSBReporter.spreporter/Contents/MacOS/SPUSBreporter
```

Which `/Applications/Utilities/System Information.app` will use to display under the branch:

```
Hardware > USB
```

Comment: But does it actually do a [re-]probe or just report what was found at some point in the past?

Comment: It does a probe at startup, and can redo it on [⌘]+[R] == refresh.

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/vulgo/IORegistryExplorer gives basically the same information as USB Prober and works on Monterey

Comment: Works in macOS 13 as well, on M1 provided Rosetta2 is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone lands here in search for a updated version of USB Prober.app: I've found the one within the iOUSBFamily for 10.9.4 (referenced above) still works in Mojave (10.14.6) and since there has been no 32bit Warning from Mojave when i started it there is a good chance it will still launch in Catalina (10.15) which has just been released.

Comment: The "Version 666.4.0 (666.4.0)" one (Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64) seems to work on Monterey (12.6) on M2 architecture.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

- USB UUIDs are information is not listed in either the **System Profiler** or `$ system_profiler`.
- USB Prober.app [no longer comes with XCode](https://superuser.com/a/814339/630402)
- `$ instruments` (which comes with XCode and requires a developer account) lists UUIDs but not for actively connected USB devices.
- [ideviceinstaller](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ideviceinstaller) wasn't able to install via `$ brew install ideviceinstaller`
- [iOSUSBFamily](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) has been deprecated since 10.9 (or possibly [10.14](https://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/IOUSBFamily/))
- Most of these solutions require XCode (~10Gb!) and an Apple Developer account - overkill for scanning USB

## Solution

I ended up installing [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) then issuing the command:

`$ VBoxManage list usbhost`

This produced a super detailed list of USB devices and their properties:

```
... 

UUID:               b28dd789-a88b-4a21-9dbb-e9398a79c0f1
VendorId:           0x05ac (05AC)
ProductId:          0x027a (027A)
Revision:           9.19 (0919)
Port:               5
USB version/speed:  0/High
Manufacturer:       Apple Inc.
Product:            Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
SerialNumber:       FM7852303J9HYMLAP+EDL
Address:            p=0x027a;v=0x05ac;s=0x0000161b9a5e0c32;l=0x80500000
Current State:      Unavailable
```

Installing a virtualizer is still overkill for this but VirtualBox is much smaller than XCode and doesn't require an Apple Developer account, plus it works on Linux and Windows.

Comment: just to make clear that all you need for access to developer tools is an apple-id. The Apple Developer Program is a paid program, but just an account at developer.apple.com is available to anyone as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

USB Prober can still be installed as of 10/19/23. I have tested on Intel (Monterey) and M1 (Ventura) systems.

1. Download from Apple developer site:  Search in downloads for 'iousb' and download 'IOUSBFamily Log Release for OX 10.9.4'
2. Mount the *.dmg.
3. The installation will likely fail if the installer is used.  Instead, do the following.

- In the mounted image, open IOSUBFamily-683.4.0-log
- Right click on IOSUBFamily-683.4.0-log.pkg and choose 'Show Package Contents'.  Open the 'Contents' folder and drag 'Archive.pax.gz' to desktop and double click on it to extract.
- Open the extracted folder, 'Archive.pax', and open DevTools|Hardware.  Usb Prober will be in the Hardware folder. You can launch it from here or move it into the Application folder.
- With the first launch of Usb Prober, you may need to give it permission to launch depending on your security settings. It may initially crash, but try to open it again.